# How to simplify Boolean expression: $(C'B')+(CB)$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm very weak in math and logic, and currently tried doing K-map, and got this as result:
$$(C'B')+(CB)$$

My question is, can this be further simplified?

I tried it myself, but I got $0$ (False).

1. $(C'C)+(B'B)$ I just swapped the places of B' and C. I don't know if can do that.
2. $0+0$
3. $0$

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot just swap characters like you did, and the simplification is certainly not $0$.

What you start with *is* simplified, and it is expressed as a *sum of products*.

Alternatively, we can write the expression as a *product of sums:*

$$\begin{align} (C'B') + (CB) &= (C'+CB)(B'+CB) \\\\
& = \underbrace{(C'+C)}_{\large =\, 1}(C'+B)(B'+C)\underbrace{(B'+B)}_{\large = \,1} \\\\&= (C'+B)(B'+C)\end{align}$$

What we have is equivalent to the biconditional (which can be read as "B, if and only if C", and which in logic can be expressed  $$(C\rightarrow B) \land (B\rightarrow C) = (B\leftrightarrow C)$$

Note that the given expression is equivalent to $(B\oplus C)'$ which reads (NOT (B XOR C)):

$$\begin{align} (B\oplus C)' &= [(BC')+(B'C)]' = (BC')'(B'C)' \\ \\ &=(B'+C)(B+C')\end{align}$$ This is, in the end, equivalent to the product of sums form (which in turn is equivalent to the sum of products form of the expression.

Comment: so is it okay to conclude that (C′B′)+(CB)=(B⊕C)′?

Comment: Sure, since it is equivalent. But you should be sure you understand why it is equivalent.

Comment: Honestly, im not sure how math logic works. as you can see the way I swap those numbers. I know that (C′B′)+(CB)=(C′+B)(B′+C) by memorizing, but I don't really understand how the process work.